# Disable Internet access (Access type) for a specific interface

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, local-area-network

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with two network interfaces. I need to disable internet access at the interface "Network 2".

Actually it is done because I configured a specific DNS on this interface and over the router that is connected to this machine (a simple TPLink with access control) I created a rule to block DNS traffic. The problem it is still showing that Internet connection is present (See "Access type" status, while the right should be "No Internet Access").

It seems to be simple, but I had some barriers while applying some solution:

1) I can't simple disable the interface because full LAN communication is required, so I also cant't remove default route or default gateway;

2) I'm not able to manage Windows Firewall for this case, because it is managed through GPO, feature that I'm not able to touch;

3) Interface 1 is fine and should remain untouched.

[Current network status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSrPJ.jpg)

Not even a block ALL in/out traffic on this interface through TPLink could change this status.

Do anybody has an idea in order to mainly change Access type status to "No Internet Access"?

Comment: `I can't simple disable the interface because full LAN communication is required, so I also cant't remove default route or default gateway` - LAN communication doesn't require a Default Gateway. A LAN by definition is a "local area network". Remove the DG from the NIC.

Comment: God! It was simple! haha! Thanks, guy! The status changed to "No internet access" after remove the default gateway, disable and re-enable the specific interface.

Answer (score 1):

In your TCP/IP settings just remove your default gateway from your interface 'Network 2'